# Get class of an element inside a link

Tags: jquery

I have an icon element inside a link, how can I get its css class with jQuery (eg. `icon`).

```
<a class="myclass"><i class="icon"></i>text</a>
```

I can get the text

```
var txt = $('.myclass').text();
```

but unable to get the class of the i.

Comment: $('.myclass i').attr('class')

Answer (score 2):

working **[FIDDLE Way1](http://jsfiddle.net/7btv7mu3/)**

Now **[FIDDLE Way2](http://jsfiddle.net/7btv7mu3/1/)**

Use folowing

```
var txt = $('.myclass > i').prop('class');
alert(txt);
```

Means inside class `myclass` find i , and then find its class property, You can also use attr.

OR

```
var txt = $('.myclass').find('i').prop('class');
alert(txt);
```

Comment: @A.V Thanks , can you explain Others why Not attr and use Prop ?Thanks

Comment: @ jQuery Angry Bird yes..., .attr() calls .prop() internally. So the .attr() method will be slightly slower than accessing them directly through .prop().

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.myclass > i').attr('class');
```